# Change MAC address in Windows 7 when option is not available

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7

I have Win7 and it does not show `Network Address`(MAC) option under `Advance` tab of `Network Properties`.

I want to change MAC address what should I do? Is it possible to change `MAC` using `CMD`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing MAC address in windows you can download and install TMAC. Just google it you will find it or download it from http://filehippo.com/download_technitium_mac_address_changer/

Comment: Original download page is at https://technitium.com/tmac